# How to prevent column to be moved in a ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have columns in a ListView. I allowed them to be moved.

Right now, I want column in position 0 to always remain at that position. So far I only set a simple code which triggers when a column is moved:

```
Is column the first one?
If yes switch it back with the column it was just swapped.
```

However, I'd like the move to be prevented, so that column 0 cannot be moved at all. Is there a way to do this? A property like "Column freeze"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle [ListView.ColumnReordered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columnreordered(v=vs.110).aspx) event. Check whether new or old index equals `0` and cancel column reordering:

```
private void listView1_ColumnReordered(object sender, ColumnReorderedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewDisplayIndex == 0 || e.OldDisplayIndex == 0)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```